# How can I have a table respect width:100% and vertical-align:middle?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with these properties:

```
table{
  background-color:silver;
  width:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

If I set `display:table`, the `width:100%` is respected but the `vertical-align` is ignored (see top table in image).

If I set `display:table-cell`, the `vertical-align: middle` is respected but the `width` is ignored (see bottom table in image).

[image]

How can I have my table elements span the full width of the container `div` and be centered vertically?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tz0wdqxL/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<table style="border:0; align:center; margin: 0 auto;float:left; width:80%" id="table1">
<tr><td>value1</td><td>value2</td><td>value3</td></tr>
</table>
</div>

<br />

<div class="container">
<table id="table2">
<tr><td>value1</td><td>value2</td><td>value3</td></tr>
</table>
</div>

How can I have both width:100% and vertical-align:middle respected by the same table? See above: only one or the other is possible.
```

CSS

```
.container{
  display:table;
  width:20rem;
  height:8rem;
  background-color:gray;

}

table{
  background-color:silver;
  width:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
}

#table1{ 
    display:table; /*respects width:100% but not vertical-align:middle */
}

#table2{
    display:table-cell; /*respects vertical-align:middle but not width:100%*/
}
```

Comment: vertical-align works on td/th , not on table https://jsfiddle.net/pg0nb1yr/ , if you want to vertical align the whole table , then make the container a table-cell to wich you can apply vertical-align: to set align content to the middle. best is to read again : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align and not get confuse of the use from a tablecell and for inline elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be missing the point but why don't you just `flex` your `.container`?

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  width:20rem;
  height:8rem;
  background-color:gray;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
.container{
  display:table;
  width:20rem;
  height:8rem;
  background-color:gray;
  align: center;
}

table{
  background-color:silver;
 /* width:100%;*/
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#table1{ 
    display:table; /*respects width:100% but not vertical-align:middle */
}

#table2{
    display:table-cell; /*respects vertical-align:middle but not width:100%*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding align: center; to the fiddle doesn't change the behaviour unfortunately.

Comment: Try using text-align: center; and let me know if it worked

Comment: Can you post html code related to this table as well?

Comment: Sure. Here's the fiddle link again while I updated the question.

Comment: Check my answer, and let me know if it helped

Comment: I doesn't work. Sorry. I do see another answer that does work though.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```html
<table style="border:0; align:center; margin: 0 auto;float:left; width:80%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>value1</th>
      <th>value2</th>
      <th>value3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>value1</th>
      <th>value2</th>
      <th>value3</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't change the behaviour when I tried it. You can see for yourself here: https://jsfiddle.net/tz0wdqxL/  - again, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want, but here's how to have horizontal and vertical centering on a table element.

```css
    .container{
      display:block;
      width:20rem;
      height:8rem;
      background-color:gray;
    }
    
    table {
      table-layout: fixed;
      background-color:silver;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    table td {
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table id="table1">
<tr><td>value1</td><td>value2</td><td>value3</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

You can achieve the same result without going through the tables

```css
.container{
  display:block;
  width:20rem;
  height:8rem;
  background-color:gray;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  letter-spacing: -0.25em;
}

.flex ul li {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container flex">
  <ul>
    <li>value 1</li>
    <li>value 2</li>
    <li>value 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```